# Convert string to int in GO

Tags: go

I am trying to convert a number into a slice of its digit in Go. My code is like this

```
    stn := strconv.Itoa(2342)
    starr := make([]int,0)
    for i3,_ := range stn {
        temp,_ := strconv.Atoi(stn[i3])
        starr = append(starr,temp )
    }
    fmt.Println(starr)
```

The error is: "cannot use stn[i3] (type byte) as type string in argument to strconv.Atoi". I am used to Python so I try to follow the idea from Python but it does not seem to work. Reall appreciate any help

Comment: As the error says, `Atoi` takes a string, `stn[i3]` is a byte. `strconv.Atoi(string(stn[i3]))` should work.

Comment: @Adrian given that `str` is a string, I think it would be more appropriate to do `str[i3:i3]`. Of course a better implementation wouldn't bother with converting to/from strings at all.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question behind the question, here's how you might convert an int into a slice of digits in go instead of using string conversions.

```golang
func digitSlice(input int) []int {
    output := []int{}
    for input > 0 {
        output = append([]int{input % 10}, output...)
        input = input / 10
    }
    return output
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/tCLISl7Djah